# Boolean Converter not hitting converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using a boolean converter in my XAML in a WPF project. I want to disable a few buttons while "IsBusy" is true. I am absolutely sure that IsBusy is being set to true/false properly. I am able to successfully bind directly to IsBusy without the converter. The following does not currently work. I've put breakpoints in the actual converter class and the "Convert" and "ConvertBack" methods are never hit. What is wrong here?

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanConverter}}"
```

Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:InvertedBooleanConverter x:Key="InvertedBooleanConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Converters:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
```

The converter:

```
namespace MyProject.Converters
 {

    [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
    public class InvertedBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(bool))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: In these cases I think you have to take a step back -- add `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />` and make sure it shows the correct class (the one that contains IsBusy).

Comment: @dbaseman Edited to clarify that I am successfully able to bind to IsBusy without the converter. I also successfully bind to it elsewhere in the same xaml.

Comment: @dbaseman I tried your suggestion though and nothing appears in the TextBlock. Maybe my DataContext is messed up.

Comment: @dbaseman I set the datacontext for the button properly to the model. Works as intended now. If you add that as an answer, I will gladly accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a step back and check that the binding is in the right place -- add `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />` and make sure it shows the correct class (the one that contains IsBusy).

Answer (score 4):

If isBusy dependancy property? if not the change form IsBusy will not be transmitted into isEnable

Comment: No, IsBusy is not a dependency property.

Comment: Why would IsBusy need to be a dependency property?  Just a regular property should be fine.